# gcc storing value of a variable at a different location

Tags: disassembly

I compiled the following program using gcc version 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 32bit with the command `gcc -ggdb -o test test.c`

```
void test(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int flag;
    char buffer[10];

    flag = 31337;
    buffer[0] = 'a';
    a = 5;
}

int main(void)
{
    test(1, 2, 3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

The disassembly of the above test function in gdb is :-

```
   0x08048404 <+0>:     push   ebp
   0x08048405 <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
   0x08048407 <+3>:     sub    esp,0x28
   0x0804840a <+6>:     mov    eax,gs:0x14
   0x08048410 <+12>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],eax
   0x08048413 <+15>:    xor    eax,eax
   0x08048415 <+17>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x20],0x7a69
   0x0804841c <+24>:    mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0x16],0x41
=> 0x08048420 <+28>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x1c],0x5
   0x08048427 <+35>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
   0x0804842a <+38>:    xor    eax,DWORD PTR gs:0x14
   0x08048431 <+45>:    je     0x8048438 
   0x08048433 <+47>:    call   0x8048320 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x08048438 <+52>:    leave
   0x08048439 <+53>:    ret
```

As much as I know, the assembly instruction after arrow corresponds to the C instruction `a = 5;` in test function. So the address `[ebp-0x1c]` should represent the address of variable `a`.
But the address that `[ebp-0x1c]` represents is `0xbffff2bc` and the address of variable `a` is `0xbffff2e0`.
I don't understand how both addresses can be different. Is this some kind of optimization done by gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not reading `a` anywhere, it seems gcc doesn't even bother reading it from the stack, and creates a local variable for it. Try replacing the `a=5` with `a+=5`, so the compiler has to read the variable, and the instruction will probably be changed to access [ebp+8], which is where the parameter should be stored.

The reason for this behaviour *might* be that gcc tries to make the 32 bit code generation more similar to the 64 bit version, where parameters are passed in registers, and need to be saved *below* the stack pointer if the compiler needs the register, or a pointer to the parameter needs to be created. Doing the same in 32 bit - at least sometimes - might help the developers share code between the 32- and 64 bit optimizers.

Comment: Yep specifically, if it's accessing the argument it should be [ebp + 8]. ebp is BFFFF2D8 so if you add 8 to that, we get the value of 0xbffff2e0 the op expected.

Comment: Replacing the `a=5` with `a+=5` did store 5 at the address of `a`. Although its useless to accept an argument which is to be modified without even reading from it once. But why is it creating a new variable and not using the one passed. One answer _might_ be what you suggested that it is trying to generate 32 bit code more similar to 64 bit version.